# WPA-PSK authentication without password

Tags: encryption, wpa2-psk

Suppose I have a service in which I allow users to share their WiFi connection. When sharing their connection, users provide their WPA PSK password to my service.

Now if somebody wants to use this shared WiFi connection, is it possible for the service to get the user connected without him actually coming to know of the password?

Further, is it possible that I can get the user connected to the shared hotspot with my service knowing only an encrypted form of the actual password?